# Moving Ubuntu to a virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, backup

I own an Ubuntu machine, that I do not have root access to. (and can not get one)

I want to have a copy of that machine as a virtual machine in my main Windows computer, so I could work on it without damaging the current machine. (and so I can just create 10 machines exactly the same)

Several notes:

- Intel NUC, running Ubuntu with GUI
- No root access as said before
- I have physical access to the device (so I can connect an external drive for the backup)
- Single snapshot, no need for scheduling stuff.
- Contents on the machine are important, and there currently is no backup.
- I have both VirtualBox and VMware on Windows.

How would I go about doing it? (backing up, and create a virtual machine out of it)

Comment: That process is known as "P2V", and you'll find a lot about this asking google (www.google.com/?q=P2V+virtualbox). Now I would go an other way: install a blank ubuntu, look at the packages installed on your orig system and re-install them on the new one, then report configurations/certificates/... although you may need administrative privileges accessing some of these stuff.

Comment: Thing is, although it is my machine, I didn't install stuff on it, and I don't wanna miss anything. I will google that though, thanks

Comment: Since you have physical access to the machine, it should be easy for you to acquire root access. Simply boot from a live USB, and you'll be able to become root very easily without special skills.